# Hide a specific output message from terminal when excuting a python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, terminal

I'm excuting a python script that utilizes `patool`library (a library for creating/extracting compressed archives).

The thing is that when I run the script, it gives me the following lines:

```
patool: Extracting D:/xx/xx/xx.xml.gz
patool: running "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.EXE" e -o D:/xx/xx/ -- D:/xx/xx/xx.xml.gz
patool: ... D:/xx/xx/ -- xx.xml.gz extracted to D:/xx/xx/
```

These obviusly are not error lines. They just tell me what's going on. **I need to hide these lines when excuting the script**. But **ONLY** this message, I mean **NOT** *other type* of messages, like error messages for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some reading I've found an easy fix to this annoying problem. The fix is in their documentation. As you can see in [their source code](https://github.com/wummel/patool/blob/edadb31a2be64d364ee8ac8f61b7f48bcbe26ab2/patoolib/__init__.py) (at this time, line 679), `patool` only print messages when `verbosity` option is **equal or greater than `0`**:

```
def extract_archive(archive, verbosity=0, outdir=None, program=None, interactive=True):
    """Extract given archive."""
    util.check_existing_filename(archive)
    if verbosity >= 0:
        util.log_info("Extracting %s ..." % archive)
    return _extract_archive(archive, verbosity=verbosity, interactive=interactive, outdir=outdir, program=program)
```

So, in order to fix your problem and hide all standard prints from `patool` use:

```
patoolib.extract_archive(path_to_file, outdir=path_to_unzip, verbosity=-1)
```

Instead of:

```
patoolib.extract_archive(path_to_file, outdir=path_to_unzip)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use a logging library (like [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)). Thus, you isolate the information due to the script's behavior (info/succes/errors) from the output of the script (what you want to show).

Comment: To clarify for others who might have made the same mistake as I: that's verbosity = -1, not verbosity = +1.  Thanks for the help